# Any .vimrc hacks to make vim automatically start a new line when you exceed line length?

Tags: line-breaks, multiple-lines

Normally, when you type text (this is just annoyance when you are taking notes) in vim, and you exceed the line length of the program, it keeps the line going but the line number isn't present:

```
100 Some text here, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah
101
```

Is there a way to make it so vim just pushes your text to the next line or creates a new one? Why do terminal text editors like vim and nano make typing over the line length kinda
annoying to deal with?

Comment: Did we addressed your question or do you still something open? Feel free to precise your question or comment such that we can help you better. If the solution fit you need maybe you can accept the answer to let the question rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

To have the desired behavior for the `text` file I would add the following line to `~/.vimfiles/ftplugin/text.vim` or `~/.vimfiles/after/ftplugin/text.vim`:

```
:setlocal textwidth=80
:setlocal formatoptions+=t
```

This called hard break. With the this setting Vim will insert a carriage return when the cursor pass the maximum value (80 in the example).

Remark: If you want the behavior to be the default behavior for all type of buffers you can add the following lines to the `~/.vimrc` file:

```
:set textwidth=80
:set formatoptions+=t
```

If you would like that Vim reformat the paragraph when inserting text you can do:

```
:setlocal formatoptions+=a
```

A paragraph is by default a list of lines separate by a blank line. But it can also be a line that end with a non white-space.

```
:setlocal formatoptions+=w
```

You can also reformat a list of lines using the `gq` command.

More information with:

- `:help textwidth`
- `:help breakat`
- `:help formatoptions`
- `:help gq`

Comment: unfortunately those lines of code have no effect on the line wrap for me when put in the .vimrc file...to be clear, i want a new line to materialize when i go over the line wrap instead of putting everything on the line, but it's not big deal, overrall vim is better for programming than any other text editor use.

Comment: If you want hat to be global to all file type you can replace `:setlocal` by `:set` and put the lines in `.vimrc`.

Comment: But if you want the settings to apply only to some file type you have to put the line in the corresponding `vimfiles/ftplugin` file e.g.: `vimfiles/ftplugin/text.vim`

Comment: But to verify that the behavior is the one you want you could just type the commands and verify that for the current buffer the behavior is as you expect.

Comment: I  tend to find that restarting vim is a the quickest and best way to test if things work, unfortunately the text is still looking it does in the question above when i go over the line wrap length even when i make it global.

Comment: The text should be wrapped when you edit it or at least when you edit the last part of the line.

Comment: Is the `gqq` command working for you?

Comment: oh, well the thread wasn't about that, but all it does is bring me to the beginning of the line like 0 or home...

Comment: gq isn't meant to be used to change line wrap settings or anything, but appears to be useful for taking a block of highlighted text and putting it all on one line.

Comment: 2 points: just changing the settings won't automatically reformat a buffer. But the `gq`  operator will, and by default respects `'textwidth'`.